# Gemfire Persistent Overflow

Tags: gemfire

I'm using Gemfire v7.0.1.3 on Linux. Below is my cache xml.

```
<?xml version.....>
<!DOCTYPE....>
<cache is-server="true">
   <disk-store name="myStore" auto-compact="false" max-oplog-size="1000" queue-size="10000" time-interval="150">
      <disk-dirs>
         <disk-dir>.....</disk-dir>
      </disk-dirs>
   </disk-store>
   <region name="myRegion" refid="PARTITION_PARSISTENT_OVERFLOW">
      <region-attributes disk-store-name="myStore" disk-synchronous="true">
         <eviction-attributes>
            <lru-entry-count maximum="500" action="overflow-to-disk" />
         </eviction-attributes>
      </region-attributes>
   </region>
  </cache>
```

Now I start cache server allocating 8GB. When I'm using String as cache key and a custom object (each object has 4 double arrays, each of 10000 size) as value, I can store 500 millions objects in the cache without any issue. I can see the disk store directory having .crf, .krf, .drf files. If I restart the cache, the elements are getting restored, all good stuff. But, if I use the custom object as key and value, I start getting low memory exception after creating 25000 (approx) entries in region. Is it expected behavior? Because Gemfire documentation says when we use persistence and overflow together, all the keys and least recently used values are overflowed to disk and most active entry values are kept in memory. So, I was expecting that, I can store any number of objects in the region as long as I have space available in my disk store. But I'm getting low memory exception. Please help me understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keys are never overflown to disk, so your memory must be large enough to accommodate all keys. For a persistent region, the keys are also written to disk, but that is only for recovery purpose. So, this behavior is expected if the size of your object keys much larger than the size of your string keys.

Comment: Thanks Swapnil. I have collected .gfs file from gemfire server and opened it using VSD provided with gemfire. In VSD there are lot of stats. For all my regions where region shortcut is "PARTITION_PERSISTENT_OVERFLOW", VSD shows "entriesInMemory" and "entriesOnlyOnDisk" and sum of these two numbers is matching with the number shown on GFMon/Pulse. I understand entry as key value pair. As VSD is saying, "entriesOnlyOnDisk", that means few entries are not in memory and residing only on disk, that means those entries which are residing only on disk, are completely evicted from memory. Isn't it?

Comment: That stat name is a bit misleading. For each entry, gemfire maintains the key and the corresponding disk location of value in memory, so that even if the value is evicted to disk, we can fetch it in one disk seek.

Comment: Thanks Swapnil. In my cache there are about 30 regions. When I configure eviction with lru-entry-count, my cache sustains for more number records but when I change eviction attribute to lru-memory-size, cache fails after few records. I suspect, because of some configuration, eviction is not happening. Is there any way to check for which region eviction is not happening? Or which operation is causing low memory error?

Comment: Also, when an entry is evicted from region due to overflow, the value is written to disk(for persistent regions) but the key remains in JVM. But at that point of time, does the key size contribute to region size? If so, then we can store N number of entries to a region, where sum of size of N keys and size of x values is less than equal to the configured region size.