# Gemfire Region Size

Tags: gemfire

I'm trying to find size of a region in my Gemfire cache. I have checked the java api of Region. The size method returns only the entry count. I'm sure there must be some way to calculate region size in terms of how much memory it is taking, because Gemfire Pulse data view it shows Memory Usage for each region. Can anyone please help on this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're after the total heap, in gfsh, do a garbage collect and it will tell you exactly how much memory your distributed system is taking in the "After GC" column.  As follows:

gfsh> connect
gfsh> gc

```html
           Member ID/Name             | HeapSize (MB) Before GC | HeapSize(MB) After GC | Time Taken for GC in ms
------------------------------------- | ----------------------- | --------------------- | -----------------------
192.168.0.10(server1:40981)<v1>:52393 | 1698                    | 120                   | 14
192.168.0.10(server2:43759)<v2>:9599  | 2250                    | 78                    | 15
```

To get the size of a partitioned region, run the following in a function on all the nodes:

```html
Region<?,?> primaryDataSet = PartitionRegionHelper.getLocalData(region);
regionSize = primaryDataSet.size();
```

For a replicated region, run the following code on one of the nodes (all code not shown for space). You have to loop through all or a sampling of entries to get the size of an average record and multiply it by the # entries. Not calculating the size of each row upon insert is by design since it would slow insert time:

```html
 /**
  * Sizes numEntries of a replicated or local region, or all the entries if
  * numEntries is 0.
  * 
  * @param numberOfSamples
  *            Number of entries to size. If the value is 0, all the entries are
  *            sized.
  */
 private Map<String, Long> sizeReplicatedOrLocalRegion(Region<?,?> region, long numberOfSamples) {
  regionTypeInd = 1L;
  Set<?> entries = region.entrySet();
  regionSize = entries.size();
  if (numberOfSamples == 0) {
   numberOfSamples = entries.size();
  } else if (numberOfSamples > regionSize) {
   numberOfSamples = regionSize;
  }

  int count = 0;
  for (Iterator<?> i = entries.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
   if (count == numberOfSamples) {
    break;
   }
   LocalRegion.NonTXEntry entry = (LocalRegion.NonTXEntry) i.next();
   RegionEntry re = entry.getRegionEntry();
   dumpSizes(entry, re);
   count++;
  }

  dumpTotalAndAverageSizes(numberOfSamples);
  Map<String, Long> results = packageResults(numberOfSamples);
  clearTotals();
  return results;
 }

 private void dumpSizes(Region.Entry<?,?> entry, RegionEntry re) {
  int deserializedRegionEntrySizeBefore = ReflectionObjectSizer.getInstance().sizeof(re);
  int serializedValueSize = calculateSerializedValueSize(entry, re);
  int deserializedKeySize = ReflectionObjectSizer.getInstance().sizeof(entry.getKey());
  Object value = entry.getValue();
  int deserializedValueSize;
  if (value instanceof PdxInstance) {
   Object actualObj = ((PdxInstance) value).getObject();
   deserializedValueSize = sizeObject(actualObj);
  } else {
   deserializedValueSize = sizeObject(value);
  }
  int deserializedRegionEntrySizeAfter = ReflectionObjectSizer.getInstance().sizeof(re);
  this.totalDeserializedRegionEntrySizeBefore += deserializedRegionEntrySizeBefore;
  this.totalDeserializedKeySize += deserializedKeySize;
  this.totalDeserializedValueSize += deserializedValueSize;
  this.totalSerializedValueSize += serializedValueSize;
  this.totalDeserializedRegionEntrySizeAfter += deserializedRegionEntrySizeAfter;
  log("RegionEntry (key = " + re.getKey() + ") size: " + deserializedRegionEntrySizeBefore + " (serialized), "
    + deserializedRegionEntrySizeAfter + " (deserialized). Key size: " + deserializedKeySize
    + ". Value size: " + serializedValueSize + " (serialized), " + deserializedValueSize
    + "(deserialized).");
  
  String histStats = "";
  try {
   histStats = histObject(re);
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  log("Hist Stats=" + histStats);
 }

 private int calculateSerializedValueSize(Region.Entry<?,?> entry, RegionEntry re) {
  Object valueInVm = re.getValue(null);
  int serializedValueSize = 0;
  if (valueInVm instanceof CachedDeserializable) {
   // Value is a wrapper
   Object cdValue = ((CachedDeserializable) valueInVm).getValue();
   if (cdValue instanceof byte[]) {
    // The wrapper wraps a serialized domain object
    serializedValueSize = ((byte[]) cdValue).length;
   } else {
    // The wrapper wraps a deserialized domain object
    serializedValueSize = ReflectionObjectSizer.getInstance().sizeof(cdValue);
   }
  } else {
   // Value is a domain object
   serializedValueSize = ReflectionObjectSizer.getInstance().sizeof(valueInVm);
  }

  return serializedValueSize;
 }

 private Map<String, Long> packageResults(long totalSamples) {
  Map<String, Long> results = new HashMap<>();

  results.put("Average RegionEntry size (serialized)", avgDeserializedRegionEntrySizeBefore);
  results.put("Average RegionEntry size (deserialized)", avgDeserializedRegionEntrySizeAfter);
  results.put("Average Key size", avgDeserializedKeySize);
  results.put("Average Value size (serialized)", avgSerializedValueSize);
  results.put("Average Value size (deserialized)", avgDeserializedValueSize);
  results.put("Total RegionEntry size (serialized)", this.totalDeserializedRegionEntrySizeBefore);
  results.put("Total RegionEntry size (deserialized)", this.totalDeserializedRegionEntrySizeAfter);
  results.put("Total Key size", this.totalDeserializedKeySize);
  results.put("Total Value size (serialized)", this.totalSerializedValueSize);
  results.put("Total Value size (deserialized)", this.totalDeserializedValueSize);
  results.put("_Region Type indicator", regionTypeInd);
  results.put("_Total Sampled Entries", (long) totalSamples);
  results.put("_Total Entries", (long) regionSize);

  return results;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Williams for your response. I have managed to get GFMon and it's showing the region size info. By the way, I had another post regarding persistent overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747762/gemfire-persistent-overflow) here. Would you mind to have a look?

Comment: ok. Before I do, can you please check the above as answered? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go and login to pulse  and navigate to following url

http://XX.XXX.XXX.XX:7070/pulse/regionDetail.html?regionFullPath=/your-region-name